# CSS - ¿Cómo puedo hacer scrollbar horizontal?

Tags: css, html5

Tengo que hacer un `scrollbar` con imagenes e información dentro, con las imagenes me funciona bien pero mi problema esta en cuando inserto información en mi `h3`, se rompe todo y no sé cómo incluirlo

Sin los `h3` me queda perfecto, el problema es cuando quiero poner el h3 encima de cada imagen, muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```css
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scrollmenu">
                <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
                <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
                <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
                <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
                <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La pregunta tal y como la formulas es algo difícil de entender, pero me supongo que el resultado final deseado son bloques de título con imagen juntos horizontalmente y que se pueda hacer `scroll horizontal`.
Ten en cuenta que `<h3>` es un `block` por defecto, por lo que sin cambiarle el `width` ocupará el `100%`. Procedo a cambiar la propiedad del `<h3>` por `display: inline`.
Contenidos en un `<div>` no pasaría nada, además sería recomendable cambiar a `inline-block` si se quiere darle una separación.

La solución es sencilla, para que puedan agruparse los elementos `<h3>` y `<a>` verticalmente, necesitas que lo contenga otro elemento así que vamos a crear un `<div>` alrededor que tenga la propiedad CSS `display: inline-block`. Esto se debe a que los `divs` por defecto son bloques que ocuparán el `100%` de `width` y nosotros no deseamos eso.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

.scrollmenu h3 {
    display: inline;
}

.scrollmenu div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
    <div>
        <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3><br>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3><br>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3><br>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3><br>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="infoImgSugerencia">Fab/Art/Desc/Color</h3><br>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="1" width="200px" height="200px"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

También te recomendaría, ya que en HTML5 no es recomendable usar los atributos width, border, etc. (que además se utilizan sin indicar `px` al final), que lo cambiases todo a CSS.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! era exactamente esooo

Comment: Podrías agregar que `white-space: nowrap;` es lo que evita que los `div` internos se bajen de linea y así obtener el scroll horizontal.